# Adding file into existing Zip Archive

Tags: java, apache-commons

So I followed the block of code here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html, where is said to simply make a ZipArchiveEntry and then insert the data. As you can see by my code below.

```
    public void insertFile(File apkFile, File insert, String method)
    throws AndrolibException {
        ZipArchiveOutputStream out = null;
        ZipArchiveEntry entry;

        try {
            byte[] data = Files.toByteArray(insert);
            out = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(apkFile, true));
            out.setMethod(Integer.parseInt(method));
            CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
            crc.update(data);
            entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(insert.getName());
            entry.setSize(data.length);
            entry.setTime(insert.lastModified());
            entry.setCrc(crc.getValue());
            out.putArchiveEntry(entry);
            out.write(data);
            out.closeArchiveEntry();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException(ex);
        }
}
```

Basically, its passed the File (apkFile) that will take the "insert" File, with another parameter dictating the compression method of that file. Running this block of code results in 0 errors, but the ZIP file only has that "new" file in it. It removes all the previous files and then inserts that new one.

Prior to commons-compresss, I had to copy the entire Zip to a temporary file, do my changes, and then copy that finalized Zip file back. I thought this library worked around that though?

Comment: did you close the `out`?

Comment: ahh, forgot something simple :/ adding the close now just overwrites the entire Zip archive to whatever File I was inserting.

Comment: You should edit the question and add that, then. Also, why use a `String` parameter if all you do is convert it to `int`? Why not use an `int` parameter already?

Comment: The incoming parameter comes in as sometimes a string / int. So to be safe, I just take it as a string and parse as an int.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question to reflect my new problem, since now the Zip file only contains the newest file, I'm trying to insert, removing everything that was there previously.

Comment: Did you find a solution? My code is either overriding existing ZIP `new FileOutputStream(zip)` or do nothing `new FileOutputStream(zip, true)`.

Comment: Over 7 years later and this is STILL an issue. I'm trying to do the same thing (append a file to an existing zip using Apache Compress) and it ends up overwriting the archive directory and shows only the new file. And the Apache Compress documentation has no examples showing how to do something as simple as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *always* want to `close()` streams when you are done with them (i.e. `out.close()`), preferably in a finally block.

Comment: Or with Java SE 7: preferably in a try-with-resources block.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative: I've written some utility methods to copy files and directories to a Zip file using the NIO.2 File API (the library is Open Source):

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html#AddZipResourceSample

API: [CopyFileVisitor.copy](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)